# Как захостить java сервер на vps?

Tags: java, сервер, tomcat, vps

Есть vps на хостинге digitalocean. Как мне захостить на него свое java приложение? Не имею подобного опыта, нужен ли для этого tomcat или я что-то путаю?

Вот Server.java:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws IOException {
        int port = 7777;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Got a client!");
            System.out.println();
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while(true) {
                line = in.readUTF(); 
                System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
                System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
                out.writeUTF(line);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто компилируете и запускаете на сервере.

Comment: А как мне его запустить на сервере? Мне нужно куда то поместить этот файл на vps или просто указать где-то в самом файле ip vps?

Comment: Так же, как обычные java-программы на обычных компьютерах запускаете. Кладёте куда хотите и выполняете в том же каталоге `java Server`.

Comment: А в каком формате нужно закинуть java файл? И для чего вообще тогда томкат нужен?

Comment: Можете сразу class-файл закинуть, а можете закинуть исходник и скомпилировать его уже на сервере.